# How to disable a drop down list with CSS, so it appears grayed out?

Tags: asp.net, css

I have an ASP.NET application with a drop down list.
How to disable a drop down list with CSS, so it appears grayed out? Is it possible to do this with only CSS ?

Answer (score 10):

I used `pointer-events: none;` and it works ok. You can even set opacity to gray it out. Create a class and add/remove it as you wish. Something like:

`.disabled {
    opacity: 0.6;
    pointer-events: none;
}`

Note that the user might still be able to use keyboard and tab to it!!

Answer (score 0):

David is right.  Another option (still non-CSS) is too loop through all the options and disable each one.  They will turn the gray color you want and be disabled.  Using a library like jQuery makes this a snap.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1075801/1150613) is almost the same question... That answer suggests using something similar to:

`<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Enabled="False">
    </asp:DropDownList>`

Answer (score 0):

CSS (Cascading Style Sheet) is made for changing style of elements, not functionality. You can do it using HTML: `Enabled="False"` for ASP.NET tags or by adding empty `disabled` attribute without value to simple HTML tags.